# R call multiple columns' elements with $ operator

Tags: r, multiple-columns

Is there something in R to call like `df$col1:df$col5`?
I would like to convert the character elements to numeric with `as.numeric`, so I would like to do something like as.numeric(`df$col1:df$col5`) to convert all elements in these columns to numeric.

Comment: `mtcars[2:5] <- sapply(mtcars[2:5], as.character)`

Comment: Since you mentioned columns: `mtcars[, 1:5] = as.character(mtcars[, 1:5])`. No need for `sapply()`here.

Comment: Probably `myMtcars <-mtcars; myMtcars[2:5] <- lapply(myMtcars[2:5], as.numeric)` is better than `sapply`, since `sapply` will result in a matrix which will then be converted to a list, and using `lapply` avoids these two conversions.

Comment: When you can't use `$`, use `[`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
df = mtcars
```

If you want to access multiple columns by column number

```
lapply(df[,c(1:3,5)], as.numeric) #Or as.character if you want
```

If you want to access by colnames

```
lapply(df[,c('mpg','cyl')], as.numeric)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a numeric index to get a range of columns, as suggested in the comments.

But if you the columns are not in order you can construct a vector of names, and use that (rather than write the names explicitly, as in the other answer)

```
my_cols <- paste0('col', 1:5)
my_df[, my_cols] <- lapply(my_df[, my_cols], as.numeric)
```